# Searching a list for match with in a range

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing a fuel millage calculator
Currently I have a List that holds travel zones.

I want to be able to search all Items in zones and find a match i.e. if I want to travel 4 miles searching the list will return the zone for "Zone 1",  If I want to travel 20 miles zone for "Zone 3" is returned,  if the distance is out side any zones no matches will be returned

```
        zones.Add(new ZoneInfo
            {Cost = 25, Name = "Zone 1", Radius = 5});
        zones.Add(new ZoneInfo
            {Cost = 40, Name = "Zone 2", Radius = 10});
        zones.Add(new ZoneInfo
            {Cost = 60, Name = "Zone 3", Radius = 20});
```

Comment: Does this mean you want to return either one or zero zones? If so, the phrase "match within a range" may be a bit confusing.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck? Please remember StackOverflow is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 1):

You need to sort all your zones according to your `Radius` value and then use `Find` to only get the first matched zone

```
const travelMiles = 5 //your defined miles
const result = zones.OrderBy(zone => zone.Radius).Find(zone => zone.Radius >= travelMiles);
if(result == null) {
   //TODO: not found any matched zone with travel miles
}
```

If your radius zones are already in order, you don't need to sort them with `OrderBy`

```
const travelMiles = 5 //your defined miles
const result = zones.Find(zone => zone.Radius >= travelMiles);
if(result == null) {
   //TODO: not found any matched zone with travel miles
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you want to return the single *most ideal* zone that covers the desired radius, if it exists.

This can be achieved by first filtering out all zones that are *not* covering your range requirement (by using [`.Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-6.0)), and then selecting the *most ideal* zone.

As the question currently stands, it is unknown to me what "most ideal" means, but I will assume *most ideal* translates to *having the lowest cost*. Finding the one zone with the lowest cost can be found by using e.g. [`.MinBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.minby?view=net-6.0), which returns `null` when used on an empty collection (e.g. in the scenario where none of the available zones cover the desired range).

It can be implemented as follows:

```csharp
var rangeToCover = 4;

ZoneInfo idealZone = zones
    .Where(zone => zone.Radius >= rangeToCover)
    .MinBy(zone => zone.Cost);
```

Both `.Where()` and `.MinBy()` are methods from the `System.Linq` namespace. `.MinBy()` requires .NET 6 (or later versions).

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2qoEd3).